# Cypress can't read the value of toolip

Tags: cypress, tooltip

I try to get the value of toolip, but as IDs and class are dynamics I do like this, but it doesn't work.

```
cy.get("#Form-WorkTaskHeaderGroup-OrganizationId")
      .find(".input-container")
      .invoke("attr", "tooltip") 
      .then((tooltipValue) => {
        expect(tooltipValue).to.equal("STJEANB");
      });
```

I have this result :

```
assert expected '' to equal **STJEANB**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nd1w.png)

Want to resolve the problem ang get the value of toolip

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget the extra text on the tooltip attribute. Use `to.match` to make a partial match, instead of `to.equal`. Or add the whole string in the equals expression.

```js
cy.get('#Form-WorkTaskHeaderGroup-OrganizationId')
  .find('.input-container')
  .invoke('attr', 'tooltip')
  .then(tooltipValue => {
    expect(tooltipValue).to.match(/^STJEANB/)
  })
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.
I have the same error
assert expected ' ' to match /^STJEANB/

I think the problem that i didn't yet locate the attribute toolip

Answer (score -1):

I find the solution. I do like this and it works. Thank you for all

```
cy.get('#Form-WorkTaskHeaderGroup-OrganizationId')
  .find('.input-container')
  .invoke('attr', 'tooltip')
  .should("eq", "STJEANB")
```